# Resetting macOS Catalina

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, restart

I have a MBP Catalina that I wish to sell. The buyer is a computer noob and would just use it for games/movies etc. He wants me to erase the thing but not downgrade it as factory reset would automatically downgrade it to an older version which I want to avoid.

Is there a way to wipe it clean to a default admin account without actually doing a factory reset? Putting it another way, is there a way to reset it without a downgrade?

Comment: See [What to do before you sell, give away, or trade in your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201065)

Comment: Also https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/221989/85275 & https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/215345/85275